# Problems deploying Office 365 SharePoint app against live Azure backend

Tags: office-365

I'm building a SharePoint 15 App for Office 365 and would like to test the app against the live deployment of its back end before I submit it to the Office Store but I am having some difficulty.

I have set-up a developer preview site and I have deployed my application code to Windows Azure but am struggling to deploy the Office 365 App itself.

The application consists of a provider hosted back-end that serves up content into a provider-hosted page and into an App Part.

As the app will be provider hosted I have performed the following steps before attempting to deploy it to my developer site...

- replaced ~remoteAppUrl with my app's Azure url (E.G. https://myappname.azurewebsites.net) in AppManifest.xml and Elements.xml.
- Replaced ClientID="*" in AppManifest.xml with the Client ID generated in the Seller Dashboard.
- Updated my consumer secret and ID in the web.config of my back-end.

When I try to deploy the app to my Office 365 SharePoint Developer Preview site I get an error message...

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install App for SharePoint': The remote server returned >an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.

If I try and deploy the app again I get a different error message

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall App for SharePoint': Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value

After this point it is impossible to remove the app from SharePoint. Retracting using Visual Studio 2012 doesn't work and deleting the app itself in SharePoint just re-loads the page and the app is still there. The only solution I have found for this is to delete and re-create the entire site collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that I don't actually need to replace ~remoteAppUrl, the ClientID or the Consumer Secret and Consumer ID, instead I did this.....

1. Unlink the app from its web project.
2. In the web application properties panel, in the *web* tab, select *Use custom web server* and enter the address of the Azure site you are deploying to.
3. Clear the *ClientID* and *ClientSecret* from *web.config*.
4. Deploy the application only to the SharePoint test site which writes in the ID and Secret.
5. Deploy the web application to Azure.